# How can I implement two factor authentication in windows?

Tags: windows, authentication, two-factor-authentication

What I need to happen is that the user enter his domain/username/password as usual, but also enter an additional token, that I can somehow intercept during the login process, authenticate it, and allow the login or not. So, effectively, the user logs in *only* if Windows allows it, *and* this secondary authentication process allows it.

Does Windows provide support for this? Some mechanism to implement this?

Answer (score 1):

All modern versions of Windows (since XP) have varying degrees of native support for two-factor authentication.  You aren't very specific in your requirements but if you only need local workstation authentication (meaning that a domain user needs 2FA to log into a specific PC) then you can do this very easily with any of the Yubikey products.  Their $20 USB token can be associated with a user on a workstation using their free software and using built in Microsoft controls.

If you want Active Directory domain-level authentication then you are going to need a product like Authlite to authenticate users.  Basically, you roll out a simple .MSI to all resources via GPO and you can either centrally enroll users OR users can enroll themselves.  Key pairings are stored in Active Directory Application partitions and all works very seamlessly.  Works with 32bit or 64bit Windows all the way up to Windows 8/Server 2012.  Currently per-user costs for Authlite are $48 total with no recurring costs.  Each user would need a USB or NFC token.

Mark Ringo